# Pure AS3 components performance test for mobile: MinimalComps vs MadComponents

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mobile

I was wondering if anyone ever made any performance test for these two libs.
I´m going to start a new mobile app and in my case flex will be a no go.
Would be great to know if there are any info about this!! Anyone?

any help more than appreciated!
Bruno

Comment: If you're looking for performance check out this GPU UI lib. https://github.com/joshtynjala/foxhole-starling

Comment: I've never used Air for mobile at all yet, but theoretically, shouldn't UI components always perform pretty well. Feel free to correct me, I'm trying to learn about how good AIR is for mobile devices myself.

Comment: @f-a Thanks f-a! I didn´t know that library and I will surely give it a try. I´m not using starling on my project since almost everything will be kind of "live" vector draw with some physics involved. there are also some components missing for what I need, like a color picker. I will probably test all 3 and check the performance...

Comment: @user1103976 Usually the native components are to bloated and heavy to use. between them and minimalComps, I would definitely stay with the second one...